# Detecting number of touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, touches

guys, I want to set actions to touches. If people make single touch - one action, else - different.
I've written this code in my touchesBegan method:

```
        UITouch *touch = [event.allTouches anyObject];
        BOOL tappedTwice = NO;
        if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
            tappedTwice = YES;
            NSLog(@"double touch");
        }
        else if ([touch tapCount] == 1 && !tappedTwice) {
            NSLog(@"single touch");
        }
```

But it's detecting single touch, and after it double, but it's incorrect in my situation. Have you any ideas?

Comment: Why not use a UITapGestureRecognizer?

Comment: Show us the code that didn't work, and explain what it did that you didn't like.

Comment: I'll bet you forgot to add the gesture to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer). Just Configure number of tap required by setting

```
[tapGestureRecognizer   setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
```

and then handle this method

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {    
       if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)     {     
         // handling code     
       } 
}
```